# Validation fails when adding script manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have a few controls on my master page for email subscription.

Web-form works fine but doesn't trigger the validation in-case one doesn't enter email address.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSubscribe" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubscribe" runat="server" >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-control form-subscribe-input" runat="server" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailSub"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailSub" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" CssClass="btn btn-maroon" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" Text="Subscribe" onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" />
                </span>
            </asp:Panel> 
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubscribeMSG" CssClass="pnlSubscribeMSG" runat="server" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubscribeMSG" runat="server" Text="">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

**Update**:

On further troubleshooting i noticed that same code works with validation on page with no masterpage.

Not sure what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was due to `script manager` as it was not able to load scripts files properly which resulted in validation failure, after spending few hours i got lucky to figure it out.

**so rather than adding script manager as**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

**i added it as**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

[link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748064/unobtrusive-validation-breaks-with-a-script-manager-on-the-page) for source of solution